# Dynamically increment/decrement the value of a variable?

Tags: python

I have a situation where the variable `max_order` is calculated depending on the value of other variables such that sometimes `max_order` is positive and others negative. Here's my code:

```
def delta_value(direction):
    diff=value2-value1
    if diff > 0: ascend="+"; descend="-"
    elif diff < 0: ascend="-"; descend="+"
    if direction == "increase": return ascend
    elif direction == "decrease": return descend

def calc_max_order():
    global max_order
    if num < max_num:
        while num < max_num:
            exec("max_order%s=1" % delta_value("decrease"))
    elif num > max_num:
        while num > max_num:
            exec("max_order%s=1" % delta_value("increase"))
```

This code doesn't seem to work (i.e. it doesn't change the value of max_order), but there are no errors returned. It stays stuck in the while loops. The code does work when `calc_max_order` is not a function, but in the main block. However, I want to make it a function to clean up my code.

I know that most people say it is unwise to use exec, but I'm just starting to learn python and I'm not sure how else to do it. I suppose I could use a bunch of if statements, but I imagine there is a cleaner way to do it.

So, to be clear, my question is:

Is there a way to either make `exec("max_order%s=1" % delta_order_value("decrease"))` work inside a function, or is there an alternative method to dynamically increse/decrease `max_order` depending on the output of `delta_value`?

Comment: what are `value2` and `value1`?  (this is one of many reasons you should avoid globals)

Comment: They are arbitrary. They are calculated elsewhere in the script. I guess I could avoid the global by using only local variables to calculate `max_order`, and then do `max_order=calc_max_order()`, or something...

Comment: Pass them as parameters! If you just pluck globals out of the ether left and right, there's no way for somebody who doesn't know the code intimately (like you do) to understand it. If you pass arguments, you can give meaningful local names to your variables and make your code much easier to understand (and debug).

Comment: Your delta value code could be simplified a lot using XOR

    def delta_value(direction):
        return "+" if (diff>0)^(direction=="increase) else "-"

Comment: @oao Not quite, it would be (diff<0)^(direction="increase"), but thanks for teaching about logical operations in python. This helped alot to really condense my code.

Comment: I just sought that your code is broken if diff==0. If this is a forbidden value, it may be safer to add an assert.

Comment: I already have a check for `value1 != value2` before, so `diff != 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `delta_value()` to:

```
def delta_value(direction):
    diff = cmp(value2, value1)   # -1 for <, 0 for ==, 1 for >
    if direction == "increase": diff = -dif
    return diff
```

*...meanwhile...*

In place of the `exec`, you can now have:

```
max_order = max_order + diff
```

Diff is either positive or negative, rather than '+' or '-'

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. You showed me how to avoid `exec` and about the `cmp` function. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The use of `exec()` is a huge red flag. You can do this with a fixed `+=` and a varying delta.

```
delta = (+1 if ascending else -1)
max_order += delta
```

And if you need to reverse the sense of `delta`, negate it:

```
max_order -= delta;
# or
delta = -delta;
# or
delta *= -1;
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me because increasing values don't always corespond to a postive delta (max_order is an exponent, and the base of said exponent can be < 1). But that wasn't stated in my question, so thank you anyway.